# Why does this inline-block element have content that is not vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Came across a weird CSS issue. Can someone explain why the box having content is not vertically aligned?

If you put text inside the span with class `.divPutTextToFixIssue` - it aligns properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/KgqJS/88/

```css
   #divBottomHeader {
        background-color: #d5dbe0;
        height: 43px;
    }
    .divAccountPicker {
        display: inline-block;
        background: blue;            
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .divAccountData {
        display: inline-block;
        background: red;
        width: 400px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="divBottomHeader">
        <div class="divAccountPicker">
           <span class="divPutTextToFixIssue"></span>                 
        </div>
        <div class="divAccountData">
            <span>Balance: $555</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The default [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) value is `baseline` which

> Aligns the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box

Note: You can see this default value in action by adding `vertical-align:baseline` to your `.divAccountData` selector. Since `baseline` is default the alignment is unchanged.

You need to change it to `top` to align the blocks at the top, for example:

```
.divAccountData {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) is defined as

> the line upon which most letters "sit" and below which descenders extend

To address *why* adding text seems to fix the problem it is because

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

from [CSS2 Visual formatting model details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading)

So adding just a single character changes the baseline, causing the second block to appear at the same vertical alignment. This **only** works if both blocks contain the same number of lines. Try adding more words to one of your blocks and you will see that without forcing `vertical-align:top` on the second block it will move depending on how many lines of text exist in the first block.

Edit: Found a related question [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to `.divAccountPicker`  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KgqJS/90/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top` in your `.divAccountData, .divAccountPicker` **class**
as like this

```
.divAccountData, .divAccountPicker {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[LIve demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/KgqJS/91/)**

If you used to `display:inline-block;`  than used to all-ways `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
.divPutTextToFixIssue {
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KgqJS/92/)