# How to get consistent line-heights between browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

This question is basically an extension of [this one about an issue I was having with vertical centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302814/how-to-vertically-center-text-in-a-block-elment-with-changing-font-size). Finding the answer to that question created a need for this question.

Have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/gys9neme/6/). It sets up a container to be 60px tall.

```
.container {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 60px;
    max-height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

In Firefox, it is `60px` tall in all cases. In Chrome, the text height is actually taller than `60px` (sometimes `69px`, sometimes other values).

I can reduce the `font-size` to `52px` to get it to line up as exactly `60px` tall in Chrome (thus giving me a perfectly `60px` tall inline element and allowing me to vertically center reliably) but that is specific not only to Chrome, but to the computer.

How can I get a consistent font height?

Comment: Are you trying to get consistent line height or font height?

Comment: Line-height, I guess. Really I want everything to be consistent.

Comment: This previous question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665541/different-line-height-in-firefox-and-chrome-when-using-text-shadow

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
font-size: 3.29em;
```

Does that work across browsers?

Comment: Nope. :D It decreases/increases font size consistently. This could only work if `em`s were applied inconsistently between browsers *in the exact inverse* to how the line-height is inconsistent between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has it's own preset styles that you might need to override. Set this at the top of your css to remove any defaults:

```
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, em, img, strong, sub, sup, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, section, time {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

And then style however you wish after.

Comment: I'm familiar with CSS normalizers. In fact, JSFiddle has one built in. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/gys9neme/7/) is what it looks like with the CSS normalized. Doesn't actually fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with texts contained in buttons and input fields. If you are using web font services like Fontsquirrel, as I am, make sure you check the font optimization option "Vertical Metrics" to "No Adjustment", under Expert Mode. Fontsquirrel defaults seems to mess up with these things.