# Why is my Layout Breaking when Inserting Content into Div Container (HTML CSS)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a simple 3 colum layout.

Whenever I insert content or images into one of the three columns, a weird margin appears either on top or bottom and the layout breaks.

Is this because I do not have a Normalizer?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3g9v611q/7/)

```
<div class="e-container">

    <div class="edate">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>

    <div class="eimage">   
         <!-- When I add this it breaks
        <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/form_image_crop.html" width="300" height="200">-->
    </div>

    <div class="einfo">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div><!-- Container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.e-container {width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
height: auto;
text-align: center;}

.edate {
    width: 8em;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.eimage {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em;
}

.einfo {
    width: 28em;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1em;
}

hr {width: 20%;}
```

**Screenshots**

This is what the layout is like without the divs holding any content...
[image: Before Content here]

The moment I add any content into any of the 3 divs...
[image: After content is added.]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Please elaborate on this "weird margin".

Comment: You are inserting an html page as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I played around with the fiddel and noticed that if you make the img display:block the problem goes away.  If your image is too tall it will still go outside of the box but other than that it works fine.

You have a set height on the DIV's so that's why the image breaks out of the box.  If you remove that height it's okay.

2) Putting vertical-align: top also fixes it.  Found that here: [Why does this inline-block element have content that is not vertically aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950479/why-does-inline-block-element-having-content-not-vertically-aligned)

Comment: I thought so too. But, what about for the Paragraph like i added in the screenshots on my question edit. Does the same apply? Should I just remove the height?

Comment: I updated my comment above with some stuff about vertical-align.  Check it out.

Comment: The 'Vertical Align' Worked (Which i found weird being I thought you needed to display as table-cell for this to work). Does anybody know where this glitch comes from?