# Set the property 'text-overflow: ellipsis' and then its sibling element's text can't align to it

Tags: html, css

```css
  p{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  span{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .left{
    width: 40%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<p class="test">
    <span class="left">TestTestTestTest</span>    
    <span class="right">Test</span>
</p>
```

And then it  will display like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS1Cs.png),
I think the reason why display like this maybe the property '`overflow: hidden`' created a  bfc, so  I set the property '`overflow: hidden`' or '`float: right`' for '.right', and then '.right' align to '.left'.

but I've seen description of BFC from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), it says that `display:inline-block` will creating a BFC,  So the BFC of each span tags should already be created because of  the css rule `span {display: inline-block}`, but why they are not align before I set the properties for '.right' ?

finally,please don't focus on my poor English, I just wanna find the answer for the question I've met, and I think I will get it by this way . Thank you!

O(∩_∩)O~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give  `vertical-align: top;` to span. Because `inline-block` default `vertical-align` is baseline.

```css
p{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .left{
    width: 40%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<p class="test">
    <span class="left">TestTestTestTest</span>    
    <span class="right">Test</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Would  you mind telling me why the default ```vertical-align``` of span can't make them align ? and this appearance is ralated to BFC or not ?

Comment: Because you use `display:inline-block`. And inline-block default vertical-align is baseline. Read answer for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950479/why-does-inline-block-element-having-content-not-vertically-aligned