# Css divs inline not next to each other when containing element

Tags: html, css

Css is always a new surprise to me.

I want to have 4 divs in-line next to each others (or 2 and 2, depends on parent size)
As long as they are empty it works. as soon the get content it breaks, as the attached example shows.

I'm very confused. How can a content of one div affect a complete unrelated div?

```css
.statistictable{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:20px;
    width: 300px;
    height:100px;
    background: #D9EFFF;
}
.statistics{
  border-bottom:5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="statistics">
    <div class="statistictable">
I'am breaking!!!

    </div>
    <div class="statistictable">

    </div>
    <div class="statistictable">

    </div>
    <div class="statistictable">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="statistics">
    <div class="statistictable">


    </div>
    <div class="statistictable">

    </div>
    <div class="statistictable">

    </div>
    <div class="statistictable">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry @Paulie_D, but I believe this question is either closed because of the wrong reason, or should not be closed at all. The question you are referring to is about vertical alignment, this question is not.

Comment: @Paulie_D, his question is not answered by the question you refer to as a duplicate.

Comment: @giorgio, @namlik Well, since adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the `statistictable` class does fix the problem, I'd say it's a pretty close hit.

Comment: @Paulie_D, well wadda ya know... i apologize then you'r right.

Comment: @Thernys Thanks
But why all the sudden do I need this? why isn't it necessary without content?

Comment: Perhaps this will explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950479/why-does-inline-block-element-having-content-not-vertically-aligned .. @Paulie_D that answer might be a better reference for duplicate

Comment: @Paulie_D Thernys is correct the issue is entirely related to baselines, and adding content to the element changes the baseline of the div

Comment: @Paulie_D please update the link to the better duplicate question, as it's answer is more correct!

Answer (score 0):

I would use span tags instead of divs as spans are by default inline. Does this give the expected result?

For example

```
<div class="statistics">
<span class="statistictable">


</span>
<span class="statistictable">
</span>
<span class="statistictable">

</span>
<span class="statistictable">

</span>
</div>
```