# Why is margin-top of an inline-element is pushing down everything after it

Tags: html, css

i have the following markup

```
<a class="block"><span class="inline">hello</span>world</a>
```

the `<a>` has a `display:block` ... if i give the span.inline a `margin-top:3px` it also pushes down the text after it. here is a jsfiddle to see this behaviour

http://jsfiddle.net/YLMeh/

could anybody give me a hint why this is happening?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `inline` elements on a row share the same line-height. If you think about it it makes sense. What would happen when you have multiple lines of text otherwise? It would be completely unreadable.

In these situation the `vertical-align` attribute is what you have to work with. Read up on that and you should be fine.

Comment: wouldnt this mean, if i add a "vertical-align:middle" to the <a>, that everything should work as (i) expect?

Comment: i need ed to add a "vertical-align:top" to the <span class="inline">... because the margin-top also pushes down the "vertical-align:middle" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top: 3px;` applied to your `<span class="inline">` pushes the baseline down for the whole text.

understanding the `vertical-align` css property may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align