# inline-block element nested in another inline-block element has an offsetTop

Tags: html, css

I'm new learning HTML and now I have some code like

```
<div id="container" style="height:300px;width:500px;font-size:0">
    <div id="leftBox" style="display: inline-block; background: pink; width: 50%; height: 100%;">
        <div id="wrapper" style="height:10%;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; background: red; width: 50%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; background: blue; width: 50%; height: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBox" style="display: inline-block; background: green; width: 50%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

(And I posted it on http://jsfiddle.net/Simon_Chan/Z3WyA/ )

You can see the `leftBox` has a big offsetTop, but if there is no `wrapper` *or* `wrapper`'s height is 100% *or* there is no `rightBox` *or* there is no elements in `wrapper`, in all these conditions `leftBox` has no offsetTop.

Why do it? And how to remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix the problem you need to add `vertical-align:top` to `#leftBox` *or* `#rightBox`

The reason is that the default [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) value is `baseline` which

> Aligns the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box

The baseline of the parent box is the bottom of the box.

[Baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) is defined as

> the line upon which most letters "sit" and below which descenders extend

All the cases you describe in the question result in the baseline being altered which aligns the elements as desired.

A good example of the *baseline* is the following code in which there are no elements in your wrapper `<div>` but very large font-size text instead. You can see how the bottom of the *green* `<div>` is aligned to the *baseline* of the parent (the red dotted border `<div>`) and how the *pink* `<div>`s text makes it move to where the text it sitting on the parent *baseline*.

```
<div style="height:300px;width:500px;font-size:0;border:1px dotted red">
    <div style="display: inline-block; background: pink; width: 50%; height: 100%;">
        <div style="height:100%;font-size:150px">foo</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; background: green; width: 50%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward helpful as well for understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

It does that because of the way the various boxes sit on the baseline. The simplest way to remove the problem is to vertically align them differently. e.g. use `div {vertical-align:top }`

To see how inline-block boxes sit on the baseline by default see http://jsfiddle.net/veCEf/. Note particularly how inline-block div boxes without any content have the bottom of their box sitting on the baseline, while once  they have content, the bottom of their content sits on the baseline.