# Is it legal to nest inline-block?

Tags: css, html

Is this valid HTML/CSS?

```html
<div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red">
    <div style="display:inline-block; padding:5px">Test</div><br />
    <div style="display:inline-block; padding:5px">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i.e. is it considered OK to nest one inline-block inside another? I'm guessing not!

Comment: It looks like the answer is _yes_. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936336/inline-block-element-nested-in-another-inline-block-element-has-an-offsettop#answer-15936705)...

Comment: "I'm guessing not!" — Why?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: css display and HTML semantic tags do not mix. nested div is valid and it has no semantic meaning. div is a neutral block where span is a neutral phrasing block. No matter if you reset display. Avalid HTML structure remains valid Use https://validator.w3.org/ to be sure

Comment: You can also check the validation of your code here https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Hi Quentin/Huangism - I assumed you wouldn't be able to nest inline blocks as I know you can't nest a block inside an inline element.

Comment: yes, it's possible. But in your snippet I see a `br` tag ! im wondering why you use it as long as you can simply change the `display` into `block` ?

Comment: ths - because I assume it IS illegal to nest a block (div) inside an inline element.

Comment: @PapillonUK You can put a block inside an inline element with CSS. `<div style="display:inline"> <div>...</div> </div>` is totally valid.

Comment: As a short answer to your main question: Yes you can nest inline-block elements. But I suggest you learn more about the behaviour of each display property value(as block, inline, flex, table...) So seeing some inline-block elements preceded by a `br` looks strange though.

Comment: ths - I agree, that's what bought me to ask this question! It is invalid HTML to nest a block element inside an inline element but as C-Cyr is hinting at above, it seems you're allowed to do that using CSS since HTML will only validate against the div.

Comment: @PapillonUK By the way, those elements are no longer referred to as block and inline elements. They do have `display:block` and `display:inline` by default, but that is not important to the HTML content model. They are not _defined_ by their CSS properties. So inline elements, for instance, are now "phrasing content" elements; see http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#kinds-of-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [html validator](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values):

> Cases where the default styles are likely to lead to confusion:
>
> Certain elements have default styles or behaviors that make certain
> combinations likely to lead to confusion. Where these have equivalent
> alternatives without this problem, the confusing combinations are
> disallowed.

Examples:

1- `<div>` inside `<span>` (block inside inline element)

2- `<textarea>` inside `<button>`

If you consider `inline-block`s either `block` or `inline` element by default, there would be no confusing behavior if you nest `inline` inside `inline` or `block` inside `block`. The only confusing combination is a `block` inside the `inline` element.

Comment: Thanks Ali - I'll mark as the answer since there are plenty of knee-jerk comments - and a mark-down(!) but no-one willing to commit an answer. The link you reference specifically suggests that nesting a block element in an inline element is invalid HTML - I would think that demanding the same from the CSS parser could also lead to confusion - something some of the commenters don't seem to have considered at all.

Comment: Please note that your second example is disallowed for a different reason than the first one!