# How to clear bottom margin of inline-block element with overflow:hidden?

Tags: jquery, overflow, css

I'm aware that when an `inline-block` element has an `overflow` property whose computed value is different than `visible`, its baseline is the bottom margin edge.

See this in practice in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hmr/) by clicking the toggle button to add  `overflow:hidden` to the `div` element. The `div`'s baseline will align with its bottom edge, generating some whitespace/margin below it.

This behavior is well explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9289377/1331430).

**My question is, how do I "fix" it so that margin does not appear when the element receives `overflow:hidden`?**

The logical fix I can think of is to change the `div`'s `vertical-align`  (which defaults to `baseline`) to something else. But I'm having trouble deciding which `vertical-align` is the most appropriate:

- `top` seems currently bugged in Chrome 33, all direct children of the element (text nodes and `inline-block`/`replaced` content) are aligned to the top edge of the `div`.
- `bottom` would be another option, but the `div` then moves slightly up/down while animating its `height`/vertical `padding` with jQuery.
- `middle` seems to work fine as far as I've tested, but I'm not sure how the resulting alignment is calculated by the browser then.

I've also discovered other hacks, such as applying `line-height:0` or `font-size:1px` in the parent and wrapping all the children in a container which resets its `line-height`/`font-size`, but those are terribly ugly hacks.

**What would be a proper value for `vertical-align`, or a proper fix for this use case?**

**Update:** `middle` will obviously align the inline-block element with the middle of the line box. So far from my testing, it seems that as long as the element's bottom edge is above the baseline, there are no flickering issues animating `height`. To demonstrate the flicker issue which happens with `text-align` `bottom`/`text-bottom` (pay attention to the top border and text): [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hmr/4/)

So a `vertical-align` of `middle` or `text-top` (to be safe) seem to work fine (avoiding `top` due to Chrome bug). I'm still open for insights.

---

Context: I'm using jQuery to animate an `inline-block` element. jQuery's animations (`fadeIn`/`fadeOut`/`slideUp`/`slideDown`/`animate`/etc) set `overflow:hidden` in the element while animating, causing the uncomfortable side-effect of having the whole page below an animated `inline-block` element to be slightly pushed down for the duration of the animation.

Here's another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hmr/1/) illustrating the paragraph above.

---

Code used in the SSCCEs:

[Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hmr/):

```
<div>
    some text and an inline block element <span></span>
</div>
<br>
<button>
    toggle overflow hidden
</button>
```

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var st = $('div')[0].style;
    st.overflow = !st.overflow ? 'hidden' : '';
});
```

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hmr/1/):

```
<div>
    some text and an inline block element <span></span>
</div>
<br>
<button>
    Animate for 1 second
</button>
```

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').animate({ width: 300 }, 1000);
});
```

(same CSS as Demo #1)

[Demo #3](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hmr/4/) flicker while animating `height` due to `vertical-align: bottom`:

```
baseline
<div>
    some text and an inline block element <span></span>
</div>
<br>
<button>
    Animate for 2 seconds
</button>
```

```
var i = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').animate({ height: ++i % 2 ? 300 : 100 }, 2000);
});
```

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a specific height to the div?

Comment: @Iqbal nope, my actual use case has dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

You could cancel the "extra" height around the expanded baseline with a negative margin, but this will be dependent on the `line-height` of the parent. This is by default about 1.2 but if you set a specific value it becomes a lot easier to handle.

Here is an example that adds a negative margin while animating:

**JS**

```
$('div').
    addClass("animating").
    animate({ height: ++i % 2 ? 300 : 100 }, 2000).
    queue(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("animating").dequeue();
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.animating {
    margin-bottom: -.2em;
}
```

Assuming default font-size 16px, the line height is ~19.2px, so we need to remove 3.2px (in em, 3.2*100/16 = 0.2). Setting an actual line height value will make this easier, of course.

http://jsfiddle.net/n6hmr/9/

Comment: I believe the default line-height varies depending on the font and the browser, but thanks this is useful info.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes it does — if you want to use this technique I suggest you set the `line-height` using explicit values rather than the browser/font defaults.