# position of division going down

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the picture, my element is going down of the nav-menu. My html is like this

```
<div class="main_menu">
    <a class="item">
        <img id="logo" src="../Data/site_images/Demicon.png">
    </a>
    <div class="item">
        <input id="searchbox">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input id="searchbox2">
    </div>

</div>
```

And the corresponding css is

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.main_menu {
  background-color: #369740;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main_menu .item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.main_menu #logo {
  margin-left: 42px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 42px;
}
```

Please explain how to change this into a div so that it occupies the parent element completely as in css or explain how to change the position of the input element.

[JSFiddle Link](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/aACrw)

Comment: Working fine for me... Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: The problem is showing up as described, in Chrome at least, here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/aACrw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `vertical-align: middle` (or `top`, really anything other than the default of `baseline`) moves us back into the containing block.

```
.main_menu .item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

Adjusting the padding/etc. on the items after that is up to you.

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/FzIuy

Some background: [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ".items" the same height and line-height than the ".main_menu", the trick here being :

```
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: [whatever]px;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpazy