# inline-block overlaps container's border in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, blink

Why inline-block overlaps container's bottom border in Chrome in following test-case?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.4em;
  background: yellow;
}
```

test-case:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/5vu2eue5

Comment: Looks like a bug. A "simpler" version: http://cssdeck.com/labs/0d2acp4c

Comment: Last point : this article can add some explanation to 'inline-block problems' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=270926&q=inline-block&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Please, star this issue, if you are experiencing the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about bullet points you can clear that with vertical-align:bottom on the link element :

```
li a {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all about calculating the `em` elements. Use round values in `em` like(0.5em, 1em..), it will give proper results.

```
li a {
display: inline-block;
padding:0.5em;
background: yellow; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/er2t19wm/1/)

Comment: Perhaps but with display:block, you don't have this problem with 0.4em