# lining up wrapped texts vertically

Tags: html, css, whitespace, word-wrap

I want to start horizontally wrapped li texts in line, now it goes upward. Please see my example

HTML

```
  <ul>
  <li>Long text goes here.</li>
  <li>Another Longer Text Goes Here</li>
  <li>Shorter text</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {width:150px;}
li {width:30%; display:inline-block;whitespace:pre-line;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wbu9ksco/

Thank you.

Comment: There's also a nice explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward you might want to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vertical align:

```
li {
   vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbu9ksco/1/)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using inline-block attribute for your li elements,
you can use vertical-align to line them up;

```
li {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```