# Elements are pushed down by other elements

Tags: html, css

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tc05vfee/

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="header-nav"><a id="branding" href="/">Branding</a></div>
    <div id="left-nav">
        <div class="header-nav"><a href="/global.php">nav item</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It ends up with the `#left-nav` and child elements being pushed down a couple pixels.

I'm not sure why the nav item is being pushed down.

Comment: add `vertical-align: top;` to `#left-nav` - http://jsfiddle.net/6L8eqok9/

Comment: @MaryMelody so what's making the container larger than it appears (is that not why it's being bumped down)?

Comment: Check this out - [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Answer (score 0):

Add `float : left;` to the containers, not the children :

http://jsfiddle.net/tc05vfee/1/