# Why do my divs act so weird when I set one taller than the others?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get some kind of a fluid layout(kind of like the Google+ one). But when I set one `div`'s `height` higher than the other, the others move according to that ones height. I have a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f1rch3zx/) to show how it looks like. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could set `.box` to `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: Also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward