# h1 breaks the design in a grid

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that whenever I add an "H1" tag to the grid like the following:

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>123</h1>
</div>
```

the grid design breaks, Please check the following example

http://jsfiddle.net/937yhqo1/

Appreciate your help.

**Update**

as @chipChocolate.py answerd that the vertical align solves the issue, but I want to know the reasons, why just when we add H1 tag(any tag with display block) the grid breaks? how does the display inline-block behave at that moment?

Comment: Did u give 
body{
margin:0px; 
padding:0px;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top` alongwith `display: inline-block` in `.box`.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 2px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>123</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, But can you explain why this happened? why just when we add H1 tag(any tag with display block) the grid breaks? how does the display inline-block behave at that moment?

Comment: @Hilmi - [Here is a complete explaination](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9289377/3905567) for that question.