# HTML and CSS Inline issue with list item

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with some inline-block divs in a list. Items that span over 2 lines are being pushed down further than the one liners. Can anyone tell me why?

You can see my issue here..

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom">I have 1 line</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom">I have 1 line</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom">I have 2 lines - im longer!</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6aqtpoee/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `float:left` in `li` elements:

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aqtpoee/5/)

```
li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 166px;
margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix the vertical alignment with `vertical-align: bottom` or another value :)

Comment: You provided the answer, but you didn't say why is this happening.

Comment: You're right. I'm kinda new here, I'll try to improve my future answers :).

Answer (score 0):

You should add `vertical-align: top` for li. It forces blocks to be aligned by its top border, not baseline.

Answer (score 0):

see this link [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aqtpoee/4/)

#### CSS

```
.top {
    height: 130px;
    background: #000;
}

.bottom {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #4f1d4e;
}

li {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 166px;
    margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the vertical-align property is baseline by default.

Change your css to:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 166px;
    margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rtsav0c/1/)

Or you can use float:left like this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 166px;
    margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3L48um/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because of the default `vertical-align` property for the `li` element, which is set to `baseline`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

"**baseline**
Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent. The baseline of some replaced elements, like  is not specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior with this keyword may change from one browser to the other."

As it mentions, that property can be unpredictable browser-to-browser, so give vertical-align a proper value like `top` or `bottom`.