# Line height moves adjecent div from the top

Tags: css

Why line hight of `<div>` - "second" affects `div`"one" by moving it from the top? [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/q3p7fbb8/)

```
<a href="#" class="one">vienas</a>
<a href="#" class="two">du</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
display: inline-block;
}

a.one {
height:3em;
border: 1px solid black;
}

a.two {
line-height:3em;
border: 1px solid black;
enter code here
}
```

RESULT:

[image: Result]

Comment: because default vertical alignment is `baseline`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are inline blocks, and siblings.
The solution could be, to apply inline-block property to just the second div, so the first div wont get height relative to its sibling block.

see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3p7fbb8/2/)

```css
a.two {
    display: inline-block;
   
}

a.one {
    height:3em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

a.two {
    line-height:5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="one">vienas</a>
<a href="#" class="two">du</a>
```

---

**Or** if you still okay with the height increased and just want to move the first div upwards you can set `vertical-align:top` for anchor

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a.one {
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
a.two {
  line-height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="one">vienas</a>
<a href="#" class="two">du</a>
```

---

**Or** if you want the element div.one to have no change in line-height and still want to let it stuck the top, just combine both the solutions: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3p7fbb8/4/)

```css
a.two {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a.one {
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
a.two {
  line-height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="one">vienas</a>
<a href="#" class="two">du</a>
```