# Why does overflow:hidden break vertical alignment of peer inline-block elements?

Tags: css

Compare these two JSFiddles:

- http://jsfiddle.net/am28dsbz
- http://jsfiddle.net/am28dsbz/1/

Why does the first show my text aligned as I expect, yet the second displays the first link lower than the second?

Stack overflow wants me to include the code from them, so here is the first:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="link1">hello</a>
        <span></span>
        <a class="link2" href="www.google.com">there</a>
    </li>
</ul>

.link1
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.link2
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The second only adds a single line,the overflow:

```
.link2
{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Duplicated check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward

Answer (score 3):

The `overflow:hidden` forces the creation of a new block formatting context. You can read about them in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting).

Answer (score 2):

@Alex W has the right answer to your question, but I will add that assigning `vertical-align: top;` to your list-item links will overcome the issue (if needed.)

```
li a {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```