# css overflow:hidden with display:inline-block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use text-overflow: ellipsis to cut some text when it is too long,but I have some problems when I use overflow:hidden with display:inline-block.

html:

```
<span class="text">
    <span class="inner left">Click to add overflow</span>
    <span class="inner right"> long text here</span>
</span>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

css:

```
.text {
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.right {
    display:inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('.text').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('overflow');
    $('.right').toggleClass('overflow');
})
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/knw7m5k2/2/

**My question is :**

- why there is 2px blank between .text element and .bottom element when the .text has overflow:hidden attribute
- why the .right elment not align with the left when it has overflow:hidden attribute
- what dose the overflow:hidden really do

my question is not how to fix it but figure out what happened

related:[Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward/9289377#9289377)

the really reason is :

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

thank you for the help of all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer to your questions as below.

**why there is 2px blank between .text element and .bottom element when the .text has overflow:hidden attribute**

A > You need to add a `vertical-align` property to align the elements to see no gaping. Link [With Vertical Align](http://jsfiddle.net/knw7m5k2/5/)

**Code**

```
.overflow {
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align: top;
```

}

***PS:*** You can change `vertical-align:top;` to any other `vertical-align` properties as per your needs.

**why the .right elment not align with the left when it has overflow:hidden attribute**

A > Alignment has nothing to do with overflow. You need to use `vertical-alignment` to align it as per you want. I also believe, that this has a link to question 1. So if you check the above, it now aligns.

**what dose the overflow:hidden really do**

> This value indicates that the content is clipped and that no scrolling
>   mechanism should be provided to view the content outside the clipping
>   region; users will not have access to clipped content. The size and
>   shape of the clipping region is specified by the 'clip' property.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visufx.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: overflow:hidden gets toggled for .text in onclick, `$(this).toggleClass('overflow');`

Comment: @PatrickEvans - My apologies. `.overflow` should be complemented with a `vertical-align` property to resolve this. I have updated the answer.

Comment: sorry for so late to reply. The default vertical-align value is baseline,I know vertical-align:top can resolve it ,but why? the default value baseline works fine before the overflow:hidden has been added, so ,my real question is what happend when overflow:hidden is added, does it damage the inline-box model?

Comment: No worries @super-xp. FYI Read this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=176244 Its chrome specification which has mentioned this as an issue. As it does not understand it, you need to explicitly add a `vertical-align` property with a `top` value to make it work, as it does not read `baseline` as it actually should. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use float:left; for both span. after that some adjustment like line-height, margin. find [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/knw7m5k2/7/)

```
.left {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
float:left;
line-height:55px;
}
.right {
margin-left:4px;    
float:left;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 100px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```