# Text in a div seems to pull the div downwards

Tags: html, css, text

I'm working on a webpage and I want it to look like those magnets (or tiles, whatever you like to call them) in the start menu of Windows 8. After some work, I got the following:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script|Architects+Daughter|Comfortaa|Handlee' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner-div">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="magnets">
            Some text
        </div>
        <div class="magnets">
        </div>
        <div class="magnets">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="magnets">
        </div>
        <div class="magnets">
        </div>
        <div class="magnets">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
html, body {
    background:#f8e4e4;
    font-family:'Bad Script';
    font-size:medium;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

.magnets {
    border:5px solid black;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.row {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:1%;
}
```

But when I open it with IE, something weird happens. The first magnet (The one with `Some text`) does not align with the other magnets. When I delete the text and run it again it's back to normal again. It seems like that it is the text that pulls the magnet downwards. I think this is very abnormal and clearly this should not happen.

I also tried this with Google Chrome but the result is the same as that of IE.

Comment: it's just happens due to display:inline-block coz inline-block default having the their own margins that changes the width of your calculations as i think so

Comment: It's better to use isotope masonry grid system (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html) because you want grid like window 8. It's good to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` in `.magnets`**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qj6uq96/)**

```
.magnets {
    border:5px solid black;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

I tested the output in Chrome, Mozilla and IE, It worked fine. If you remove   `width:100%;` from `html, body` , Its giving similar output

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain why this happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward this link might be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Or you could set `vertical-align: bottom;` on the `.magnet` class.

EDIT:

The reason for this is that, because the .magnet classed blocks are redefined as being inline-blocks, the blocks are treated as though they were text, so they all have their bottoms line up on a base line by default.

Whenever one of these blocks contains text, the default "anchor" to the base line shifts from the bottom of the block itself to the text inside the block, and the block itself just becomes a kind of border around the text without meaningful anchor points. To force the block to realign with its siblings, you need to override this default behaviour by explicitly defining `vertical-align: bottom;` on the block so that it will align to the bottom of the base line, just like text will align itself to the bottom of the base line by default, since text is also displayed inline.

Some more reading on this:

- http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/

/EDIT

Link to the result: http://jsfiddle.net/e1og1m8v/, or a local runnable snippet to elaborate:

```css
html, body {
    background:#f8e4e4;
    font-family:'Bad Script';
    font-size:medium;
    text-align:center;

    width:100%;
}

.magnets {
    border:5px solid black;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.row {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:1%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="banner-div">

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="magnets">
            Some text
        </div>

        <div class="magnets">

        </div>

        <div class="magnets">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="magnets">

        </div>

        <div class="magnets">

        </div>

        <div class="magnets">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain why this happens?

Comment: It's not easy to grasp, this concept of vertical-align combined with inline elements, but I have tried nonetheless.