# Vertical-align baseline not working

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple setup:

```
<button>
    Lorem
</button>
<input type="text" value="Ipsum">
```

with both elements next to each other using `display: inline-block`:

```
button, input{
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/j02ypo0v/

[image]

As you can see, the two elements are not perfectly aligned (off 1px).

I know, I could easily solve this by changing `vertical-align` to `middle`, but I want to understand *why* this offset is present in the first place.
IMO, it doesn't make any sense that the two elements are not perfectly vertically aligned since they share all CSS attributes (especially `height`, `line-height`, `display` and `vertical-align`).

Can anybody explain me where the 1px offset is coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Comment: Did you notice that if you increase or decrease line height by one pixel the error goes away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `baseline` alignment is to do with the positioning of the text rather than the positioning of the element as a whole. If we zoom in on the `button` and `input` elements and add a straight line below the text, you'll see that the text in both elements is in fact vertically aligned at the same position:

[image: Example]

I can't tell you what the exact cause of the problem is, but what I do know is that if you reduce the `line-height` to `32px` or increase it to `35px` the two elements become in line with each other whilst keeping the text in line as well:

[image: Example 2]

My guess is that there's a difference in calculation on the browser side of things when using a `line-height` of `34px` and a `font-size` of `14px` between a `button` and `input` element as in your example, as if we do change the `vertical-align` to `middle` as your question suggests the text is no longer in line:

[image: Example 3]

Answer (score 0):

It's because a button is replaced inline element.

MDN says about line-height:

> On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that
>   is used to calculate line box height. On replaced inline elements such
>   as buttons or other input element, line-height has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following:

- padding: 0, since the input will naturally have padding
- height: 34px, since you already use the line-height

Find the results here: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/j02ypo0v/26/)

```
button, input{
    line-height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have added a yellow div container so it's easier to see.