# Div's not aligned one next to the other

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with this: https://jsfiddle.net/xfpfjqw0/

```css
header .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 40%;
}
header .search {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="search">
    <form action="/search/" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="q">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

It's an excerpt from a website I'm building. If you inspect the two elements you will see that the first one starts at the top-left but the second one on the down-right of the first one.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have to specify the `vertical-align` of the element to change the alignment. The default value is `baseline` but you can change it like for example `top`, `middle`, `bottom`

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/xfpfjqw0/1/)

See a larger explanation of this right here : 
[Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Comment: The default of `vertical-align` is `baseline`, so actually the boxes already have a `vertical-align`, and adding `vertical-align: baseline` doesn't solve the issue. So why do you have to specify another value than `baseline`? There is a specific reason which you failed to mention, but fortunately the answer of the duplicate question *does* provide all the information, context and literature.

Comment: True, it was unclear in my answer. But I've specified the default value is `baseline`. You can specify it to change its default value, that's what I've wanted to meant.