# Inline-block and movement of first child div

Tags: html, css

I just started learning CSS, now stuck at this part. what makes the brand class to move down when information class is inline-block-ed? Doesn't information comes after brand so it shouldn't affect the brand class?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #ACDACD;
}
.brand {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.information {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="brand">AKKJKJKJKJKJFKJDKFJDKJF
  </div>
  <div class="information">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainbody">

</div>
```

Comment: Here is a very lengthy answer to this query. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9289377/2952405

Comment: @InQusitive - re your comment on my answer - good point :/ - thats what I get for not paying attention to the code, just looking at the results and jumping to conclusions! One thing for you to take into account, is if you add text to `information` they line up perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `vertical-align`ment of text is `baseline`. The difference in the `height` is what makes it. If you have this CSS rule:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Or whatever it is perfect, it looks alright. See below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #ACDACD;
}
.brand {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.information {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="brand">AKKJKJKJKJKJFKJDKFJDKJF</div>
  <div class="information"></div>
</div>
<div class="mainbody">

</div>
```

And now the difference or the white line is because of the `border`, which can be made by using `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #ACDACD;
}
.brand {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.information {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="brand">AKKJKJKJKJKJFKJDKFJDKJF</div>
  <div class="information"></div>
</div>
<div class="mainbody">

</div>
```