# Why div are not aligned horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 2 `div`s horizontally  inside one `div`.

Here is codepen link [Check Here](https://codepen.io/vtarun/pen/wrqdMY). When I add margin-top to left `div` it is not moving up.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<footer id="contact">           
    <div class="reservation" style="display: block;border:1px solid red; "> 
        <div class="reserve-address-div" style="display: inline-block;width:45%;border:1px solid red;margin-top:-40px;">        

            <h4>51 Area, Barmuda Triangle, Mars</h4>
            <h4>0165466546</h4>
            <h4>vivek.tarun17@gmail.com</h4>        

        </div>
        <div class="reserve-booking-div" style="display: inline-block; width:45%;border:1px solid red; ">                       
            <form>
                <input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br>           
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><br>
                <input type="text"  name="subject" placeholder="Subject"/><br>
                <textarea placeholder="message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
                <input type="button" value="Submit">
            </form>     
        </div>  
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why are you only using inline styles? You should move all styles to a separate file (or use the CSS section in codepen).

Comment: remove `margin-top` and add `#contact .reservation > div {
  
  vertical-align: top;
}`... see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/borWwO ?

Comment: why margin-top is not working..Theoretically it should work rt?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `vertical-align: top` something like this:

```
<div class="reservation">   
    <div class="reserve-address-div" style="display: inline-block; ... vertical-align:top">     
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="reserve-booking-div" style="display: inline-block; ... vertical-align:top"> 
        ...
```

`vertical-align` property is useful.

You can put inline-blocks along with the top of parent element, e.g., `div`.

Answer (score 1):

How about the ***Flexbox*** solution:

```css
.reservation {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2.5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.reserve-address-div, .reserve-booking-div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 2.5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<footer id="contact">           
  <div class="reservation"> 
    <div class="reserve-address-div">        
      <h4>51 Area, Barmuda Triangle, Mars</h4>
      <h4>0165466546</h4>
      <h4>vivek.tarun17@gmail.com</h4>        
    </div>
    <div class="reserve-booking-div">                       
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>           
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br>
        <textarea placeholder="message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit">
      </form>     
    </div>  
  </div>
</footer>
```

Adjust `margin`s and `padding` to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `.reserve-address-div` is being pushed down is because the default `vertical-align` value is set to `baseline`. As another poster mentioned, setting the `vertical-align` property to `top` for `.reserve-address-div` will remove the space above that div.

You can read more about the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward).

An alternate solution would be to use `flexbox` on the `.reservation` container, as I've demonstrated in the snippet below.

Hope this helps!

```css
.reservation {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.reserve-address-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.reserve-booking-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<footer id="contact">
  <div class="reservation">
    <div class="reserve-address-div">

      <h4>51 Area, Barmuda Triangle, Mars</h4>
      <h4>0165466546</h4>
      <h4>vivek.tarun17@gmail.com</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="reserve-booking-div">
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" /><br>
        <textarea placeholder="message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply .. yes it is working. i used vertical-align: top. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @VivekT you're welcome & good to hear. Please be sure to mark as answered!