# Why Does The Margin From An Inline-Block Element Affect A Sibling Inline-Block Element

Tags: html, css, web, layout, css-position

I can't figure out why the `margin-top` of the `<nav>` element ( which comes after the `<hgroup>` element ) affects the `margin-top` or the placement of the `<hgroup>` . By adding a top margin to the `<nav>` element, the `<hgroup>` element also moves down as if it also has a `top-margin` applied to it

```css
heading {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

heading hgroup {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Avenir";
  font-size: 5em;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 500px 0 0 -1.618em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<heading>
  <hgroup>
    <h1>NERD</h1>
    <h1>CO.</h1>
  </hgroup>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">podcast</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">social</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</heading>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inline-block` element behaves like an `inline` element in that it will be subject to positioning attributes such as `line-height` and `vertical-align`. Once you increase the `margin-top` of `nav` past `500px` or so, the height of the line is larger than the height of the `hgroup`. The default `vertical-align` of `baseline` pushes `hgroup` down. In other words, the elements are positioned according to the inline flow.

Please note, in the snippet below, that when I set `vertical-align` to `top` than the `hgroup` is placed at the top of the line.

```css
heading {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

heading hgroup {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Avenir";
  font-size: 5em;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 550px 0 0 -1.618em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<heading>
  <hgroup>
    <h1>NERD</h1>
    <h1>CO.</h1>
  </hgroup>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">podcast</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">social</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</heading>
```