# Tic Tac Toe HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was trying to create a basic tic tac toe game with React (but this question is just about CSS).

Initially, I wrote the following code for the grids:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Square from './Square';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div><Square /><Square /><Square /></div>
        <div><Square /><Square /><Square /></div>
        <div><Square /><Square /><Square /></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

where each Square is just an empty div (so I'll omit the Square.js code here), which has the following style:

```
{
  backgroundColor: "white",
  border: "black solid 2px",
  textAlign: "center",
  fontSize: "20px",
  width: "40px",
  height: "40px",
  margin: -1,
  display: "inline-block",
}
```

What happened was the Squares jumped up and down when rendering "X", "O" and the empty string like so:

[image]

Then I consulted React's official tutorial's code, where they did it differently in 2 ways:

- In Square's CSS, the added "float: left" instead of my "display:
  inline-block"
- They added another class "board-row" for each row, i.e. for each of the 
  the div that wraps around the 3 Squares, with the following CSS:

  ```
  .board-row:after{
        clear: both;
        content: "";
        display: block;
  }
  ```

  My question is:
- Why wasn't my code working?
- Why is the new code working?

I do have some initial thoughts: The new code has the squares of each row to float left, then it creates an empty element with "clear: both", which moves the empty element below the floated squares, forcing the next row of Squares to go below. (without "clear: both" all 9 squares will be on the same row). "display: block" also gives the empty element the ability to push the squares around.

Does it make sense? I also have trouble explaining what's the problem with the original code.

Normally I wouldn't care as long as the code is already working, but I'm trying to teach someone else React, so I want to be able to explain to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding

```
verticalAlign: "top",
```

to the intial style will be enough as per this [blog](https://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/).
I tried it out in your intial style and it worked. You dont have to add `.board-row:after`

Comment: holy cow that's amazing!

Answer (score 0):

**Why is the new code working?**
Because it uses floating property to get the desired layout. You tried to achieve the same by using  `"display: inline-block"` and that called an issue. I've found a great explanation of it here: [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward/31337574)

Still, your solution is not wrong, just add `overflow: hidden` and `line-height` equal to font size to get text vertically centred. Also you've missed **"px"** in margin property

```
.square {
  background-color: white;
  border: black solid 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/bMxxOo?editors=1100

Comment: "margin: -1" works because I wrote it as a style object in JavaScript, not CSS. Anyways, thank you for the explanation! Sometimes the nuances in HTML and CSS can be so frustrating