# parent div height is incorrect when it contains another empty div with display: inline-block,

Tags: css

I ran into issue where parent div height is larger than the contents and I'm trying to understand why.

Specifically child div has display: inline-block and no contents. padding, margin, border are all 0;

What's interesting that adding any content, even nbsp, fixes the issue.

Is this a browser bug or by design?

```html
why parent div height is larger than child div?
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block'></div>
</div>

<hr>

adding any content fixes sizing
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block'>
    x
  </div>
</div>

& nbsp; works too

<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the following, scroll down to the results section and check out the differences between ***inline-block*** and ***block*** particularly with your issue in mind... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_value_comparison

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo changing to flex or grid doesn't really solve the problem because it changes the behavior and we no more have the baseline alignment issue happening here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by design and is related to the baseline alignment. To understand what is happening add more text inside your container

```html
why parent div height is larger than child div?
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block'></div>
  p
</div>

<hr>

adding any content fixes sizing
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;color:#fff'>
    x
  </div>
  p
</div>

& nbsp; works too

<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;color:#fff'>&nbsp;</div>
  p
</div>
```

In the 3 cases, the `inline-block` is aligned with the baseline but the baseline of an empty `inline-block` element is its bottom edge so you have that bottom space that is for descender.

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading)</sup>

You will also have that issue in the 3 cases if you add `oveflow:hidden`

```html
why parent div height is larger than child div?
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;overflow:hidden'></div>
  p
</div>

<hr>

adding any content fixes sizing
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;color:#fff;overflow:hidden'>
    x
  </div>
  p
</div>

& nbsp; works too

<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;color:#fff;overflow:hidden'>&nbsp;</div>
  p
</div>
```

To avoid this you simply change the alignment to something different than baseline:

```html
why parent div height is larger than child div?
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:top;'></div>
  p
</div>

<hr>

adding any content fixes sizing
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;color:#fff;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:top;'>
    x
  </div>
  p
</div>

& nbsp; works too

<div style="background-color:red;">
  <div style='background-color:blue; width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block;color:#fff;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:top;'>&nbsp;</div>
  p
</div>
```

Related:

[Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9273016/8620333)

[Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/8620333)

Comment: Interesting... is it possible to achieve it without the extra text ?

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo the extra text is irrelevant here (you can remove it). I simply used it to highlight the alignment of the inline-block