# Inline elements do not line up when content is added

Tags: html, css

I am surprised that inline elements do not line up even though they have mathematically the same height.

One element has a height of 50px and the others have a height of 44px + 3px padding (= 50px height).

I have found some posts that say to use vertical-align: top;. But it is not clear to me why this is related to the content.

Without content they are displayed in a line, but as soon as I add content (text), the elements with height 50px are pushed down.

What is the reason for this and how can I change it?

HTML-Code

```
<div>
  <span class="x">x</span>
  <span class="y">x</span>
  <span class="x">x</span>
<div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  height: 50px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.x {
  height: 50px;
}

.y {
  height: 44px;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox ? The devtool allows to see how elements are placed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Comment: Not really. I used the same text in all spans (i.e. without g, y, q, ...) so that the baseline is not affected. I also have not changed the overflow of the div.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS Code, add `vertical-align:top` in the `span` like this:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

here's snippet:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x {
  height: 50px;
}

.y {
  height: 44px;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="x">x</span>
  <span class="y">x</span>
  <span class="x">x</span>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Setting vertical-align to top solves this problem, but I would like to understand why adding a content (text) changes the alignment.

Answer (score -1):

You can align them with f.e. `display: flex`

This has nothing to do with your issue but: read about `em` and `rem`units for better scalability of your desing.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.x {
  height: 50px;
}

.y {
  height: 44px;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="x">x</span>
  <span class="y">x</span>
  <span class="x">x</span>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The flex layout solves this problem, but I would like to understand why adding a content (text) changes the alignment.

Comment: Default value of `vertical-align` for `inline-block` is `baseline` which is trying to keep all the *x* on one level (this is happening in your original example). But one of the *x* is moved a little bit because of the padding you are adding. In order to keep all *x* on one level (in one line), the elements have to be misaligned. When you set the `vertical-align:top` it wont try to keep the *x* in line but will align the `inline-block` element on top. I tend to use `flex` on everything as it usually solves all my problem quickly. In this case is the `vertical-align:top` maybe a better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have understood it. The baseline refers to the text and not to the lower area of the box.