# In Bootstrap 4, hiding two adjacent columns on mobile stacks them. How can I prevent this?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hiding a single column on a mobile device using `d-none d-md-block` works fine, but if I have two adjacent columns I want to hide on mobile, they come out stacked on desktop.

```
 <table width="80%" class="tabTable table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
   <tr><th class="d-none d-md-block">Col 1</th><th class="d-none d-md-block">Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th></tr>
   <tr><td class="d-none d-md-block">Val 1</td><td class="d-none d-md-block">Val 2</td><td>Val 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="d-none d-md-block">Val 1</td><td class="d-none d-md-block">Val 2</td><td>Val 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comes out like

[image]

Adding style="vertical-align:top;" to the `<th>` and `<td>` in the first two columns does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward

Comment: Also, is it possible to use this type of division or do you require it in table format?
<div class="col-md-6"  ></div><div class="col-md-6"  ></div>  Just in personal experience all the td and trs and what not can get overwhelming in your IDE and its just visually easier working on non tabled data that you CSS style to look like a table instead as a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to restructure this - I was hoping there was a fix within the td and th like in the linked answer.

Comment: Your hint was helpful @easleyfixed - see comment below accepted answer and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td` has by default `display:table-cell;`. `d-md-block` changes its `display` to `block`. Block elements take all the available space.

Since one of the `td` has `display:table-cell;` and the other two have `display:block`, they look so.

---

Use `d-md-table-cell` instead of `d-md-block` every where.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table width="80%" class="tabTable table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Col 1</th>
    <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Val 1</td>
    <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Val 2</td>
    <td>Val 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Val 1</td>
    <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Val 2</td>
    <td>Val 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also discovered: using `vertical-align:top` *will* work if `d-md-block` is changed to  `d-md-inline`.  Thanks to @easleyfixed.

Comment: @ScottCWilson you do not need to use `d-md-inlne` because it sets `display` to `inline`.

Comment: But without this, how would it know to hide on small and xs screens?