# I created four divs with display:inline-block. I added a span to one div. This div moves vertically from its position. I don't want this to happen

Tags: html, css

- I created four divs
- I added a span to one of the divs
- However, when I added the span, it moves vertically downwards from its normal position
- I do not understand why this is happening

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #686868;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="a1"><span>xyz</span></div>
<!-- this div element is moving from its original position -->
<div class="div" id="a2"></div>
<div class="div" id="a3"></div>
<div class="div" id="a4"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `display: inline-block` instead of flexbox?

Comment: I was learning display:inline-block and tried to implement on div . I could do with Flexbox using display:flex and flex-direction:row to the main container and it will display. However I thought what is the reason why the div is moving when I insert span element in it. This behaviour is quite abnormal

Comment: Hint: when you use `inline-block` and the element is taller than the parent _flow container_'s `line-height` you'll encounter unexpected-but-actually-very-well-defined vertical-alignment issues like this.

Comment: How should I fix this Dai. Is there any solution for the given code

Comment: That depends on what end-result you want. If you want to have some boxes in a line containing text then you should use `flex` instead of `inline-block`. You _can_ make it work as-is by playing with `vertical-align:` and `line-height:` but it feels like a hack to me because you end-up abusing a `flow` context.

Comment: when I added overflow:hidden to my inline-block element it worked. I don't know the reason but someone mentioned about overflow:hidden in the article.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward