# Two divs same line: why overflow: hidden; causes vertical offset?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs sitting one next to the other on the same line with `display: inline-block;` https://jsfiddle.net/3q0kbv2k/. When I put `overflow: hidden;` on the first div, the second is moved down by a small offset.

Html:

```
<!-- CODE ON ONE LINE ON PURPOSE -->
<!-- WHITESPACES BREAK LAYOUT -->
<div class="foo">foooooooooooooooooooooo</div><div class="bar"><div>bar</div></div>
```

Css:

```
.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: red;
}

.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Why is this happening?

I found [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789854/overflow-hidden-causing-alignment-issues-in-firefox) that depicts the very same scenario and contains a workaround, but I'm interested in understanding **why** this happens, is it a bug or normal behaviour?

Comment: It's described at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow); "**overflow: hidden The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.**" I'm not sure that's the answer you're looking for though?

Comment: why just put `overflow:hidden` on `.bar` and they'll line up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward)

Comment: I think it's an inline-block thing. You can fix it by adding `div { vertical-align: top; }`, although that's not an explanation to why it's happening.

Comment: Just add `overflow: hidden` to BOTH, problem solved. The question @showdev provided contains your explanation, look at the bold text in accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [**spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Your `foo` div has an overflow "other than visible," so its baseline is the "bottom margin edge."

Your `bar` div has visible overflow, so its baseline is the baseline of its text.

You can fix this by giving them the same `vertical-align` style:

```css
.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">foooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
<div class="bar"><div>bar</div></div>
```

Comment: This is also explained in the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward#answer-9289377), though your post is arguably more concise.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see your comment until after I posted.  Looks like a good read.